# How do I install updates that Ubuntu 16.04 has downloaded?

Tags: 16.04, updates, downloads, notification

I get a notification in the top-right corner that says that Ubuntu has downloaded updates and is ready to install them.  But I can't click on the notification or otherwise actually install the updates.

Whenever I move the mouse to the notification, it "blurs" (turns grey and unreadable) and doesn't respond to mouse clicks, but I move the mouse away from the notification and it comes back into focus.  Then it disappears entirely (which is why I can't quote the message; it's lost forever AFAIK).

How do I get the box to stop blurring and actually respond to mouse clicks? Why is there a notification that can't be responded to?

The real question: if I see this notification that updates have been downloaded, how do I actually install those updates?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what the blurred box looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to ditch the GUI way of installing updates altogether, then you can just install them using the terminal. Start a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type in the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I'm not entirely willing to ditch the GUI way.   It does seem counterintuitive that the GUI will show that there are downloaded updates but not show a way to actually install them.

But I'm not averse to using bash.